# How to mark entries that do not satisfy a statement in a try loop

Tags: python

I am trying to determine the rise & fall time of a signal, which looks like this:[PMT Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFDPX.png)

The goal is to find the fall and rise time of the signal. What I have tried is to assign a 90 percent level in the flat part of the signal and assign the 0-10 % as the minimum of the signal. Here's what I have tried:

def drop_time(self, ch, calChannel_data):

```
    try:
        up_limit = np.where(calChannel_data >= np.percentile(calChannel_data, 90, axis = 0) )
        low_limit = np.where(calChannel_data == np.min(calChannel_data))
        midpoint = np.where( np.logical_and(calChannel_data >= np.percentile(calChannel_data, 45, axis = 0), \
                                        calChannel_data <= np.percentile(calChannel_data, 55, axis = 0)))
        before_fall =up_limit[0][ np.where(up_limit[0] <= low_limit[0][0])]
        after_fall = up_limit[0][np.where(up_limit[0]>= low_limit[0][0])]
    except IndexError:
        print("the criteria was not met") 
    else:
        return  ch, up_limit[0], low_limit[0][0], midpoint[0], before_fall, after_fall
    finally: 
        print("the end")
```

However, it doesn't fully work for there are parts of the signal that don't satisfy the condition in the try: part of the code. Is there a way to mark any instances where the condition wasn't satisfied and prevent it from stopping?

Answer (score 0):

You could always nest `try`s, something like

```
try:
    try:
        up_limit = np.where(calChannel_data >= np.percentile(calChannel_data, 90, axis = 0) )
    except:
       up_limit = "Failed" # or whatever
    # ... similarly for the others
    low_limit = np.where(calChannel_data == np.min(calChannel_data))
    midpoint = np.where( np.logical_and(calChannel_data >= np.percentile(calChannel_data, 45, axis = 0), \
                                    calChannel_data <= np.percentile(calChannel_data, 55, axis = 0)))
    before_fall =up_limit[0][ np.where(up_limit[0] <= low_limit[0][0])]
    after_fall = up_limit[0][np.where(up_limit[0]>= low_limit[0][0])]
except IndexError:
    print("the criteria was not met") 
else:
    return  ch, up_limit[0], low_limit[0][0], midpoint[0], before_fall, after_fall
finally: 
    print("the end")
```